Terraform throws 'Error: Cycle: ' with modules
I am using the modules to create a lambda, IAM and policies. Which is working fine but a few of the resources end with cycle errors.  Terraform version and the codes are given below.
Version - Terraform v1.3.2
Code:
module "certissue_lambda" {
  source        = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version       = "7.0.0"
  function_name = "acmpca-certIssue"
  description   = "Acmpca certIssue Transform"
  handler       = "certIssue.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.9"
  timeout       = "60"
  create_role   = false
  #lambda_role   = aws_iam_role.cert_issue_lambda_role.arn
  lambda_role = module.iam_assumable_roles["ert_issue_lambda_role_test"].iam_role_arn

  source_path                   = "${path.module}/python/certIssue.py"
  attach_cloudwatch_logs_policy = true

  layers = []
  environment_variables = {
    SigningAlgorithm = local.signing_algorithm
    PCAarn           = aws_acmpca_certificate_authority.private_ca_authority.arn
    CSR_PATH         = local.csr_path
    SNS_TOPIC_ARN    = aws_sns_topic.failed_cert_rotation_sns_topic.id
  }

  tags = local.tags
}

module "iam_assumable_roles" {
  for_each = local.iam_roles
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-assumable-role"
  version  = "v5.41.0"

  create_role       = true
  role_requires_mfa = false

  role_name                       = each.key
  custom_role_policy_arns         = each.value.custom_role_policy_arns
  create_custom_role_trust_policy = each.value.create_custom_trust_policy
  custom_role_trust_policy        = each.value.custom_role_trust_policy
  trusted_role_arns               = each.value.trusted_role_arns
  trusted_role_services           = each.value.trusted_role_services
  tags                            = local.tags
}

module "iam_policies" {
  for_each = local.iam_policies
  source   = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-policy"
  version  = "v5.41.0"
  name     = each.key
  path     = "/"
  policy   = each.value.policy

  tags = local.tags
}

locals {
  iam_roles = {
    "cert_issue_lambda_role_test" = {
      create_custom_trust_policy = "false"
      custom_role_trust_policy   = ""
      custom_role_policy_arns = [
         "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
      ]
      trusted_role_services = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      ]
      trusted_role_arns = []
    }
  }
  iam_policies = {
    "cert_issue_lambda_policy_test" = {
      description = "Cert Issue lambda policy"
      policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [
          {
            Effect = "Allow"
            Action = [
              "ssm:SendCommand",
              "ssm:GetCommandInvocation",
              "dynamodb:PutItem",
              "acm-pca:IssueCertificate",
              "sns:Publish"
            ]
            Resource = ["*"]
          }
        ]
      })
    }
}

Steps to reproduce - terraform init  and terraform apply
Error:

│ Error: Cycle: module.iam_policies.output.path (expand), module.iam_policies.output.arn (expand), module.iam_policies (close), module.iam_policies.output.policy (expand), module.iam_policies.output.name (expand), module.iam_policies.output.description (expand), module.iam_policies.var.path (expand), module.iam_policies.var.name_prefix (expand), module.iam_policies.var.name (expand), module.iam_policies.var.description (expand), module.iam_policies.var.tags (expand), module.iam_policies.var.policy (expand), module.iam_policies.var.create_policy (expand), module.iam_policies.aws_iam_policy.policy, module.iam_assumable_roles.var.custom_role_trust_policy (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.local.custom_role_trust_policy_condition (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.tags (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.max_session_duration (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_permissions_boundary_arn (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role, module.iam_assumable_roles.var.force_detach_policies (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.create_role (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_description (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.mfa_age (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.data.aws_partition.current, module.iam_assumable_roles.local.partition (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.allow_self_assume_role (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.create_custom_role_trust_policy (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.trusted_role_actions (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_name_prefix (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_name (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.local.role_name_condition (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.trusted_role_services (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_sts_externalid (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.local.role_sts_externalid (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_path (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.trusted_role_arns (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.data.aws_caller_identity.current, module.iam_assumable_roles.local.account_id (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_session_name (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_requires_session_name (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_with_mfa, module.iam_assumable_roles.aws_iam_role.this, module.iam_assumable_roles.output.iam_role_arn (expand), module.certissue_lambda.var.lambda_role (expand), module.certissue_lambda.aws_lambda_function.this, module.certissue_lambda.output.lambda_function_arn (expand), module.certcheck_lambda.var.environment_variables (expand), module.certcheck_lambda.aws_lambda_function.this, module.certcheck_lambda.output.lambda_function_arn (expand), local.iam_policies (expand), module.iam_policies (expand), module.iam_policies.output.id (expand), local.iam_roles (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles (expand), module.iam_assumable_roles.var.role_requires_mfa (expand)
│

I've tried adding depends_on on the lambda module: depends_on = [module.iam_policies, module.iam_assumable_roles]. Any suggestion?

Would you mind explaining what does "Which is working fine but a few oft he resources end with cycle errors." mean? The list is quite long.

Is there more to this? The code example you've provided doesn't seem to have any cyclic dependencies between the modules. Adding an explicit depends_on won't help when it comes to cyclic dependency issue

@MarkoE I'm following the same setup to create other lambda functions, which works fine.

@AmirAsyraf Nope. I've provided all the codes related to this module's creation.  Yes, I am also not seeing any dependencies and that's where I got confused.

@MarkoE Check the following Gist for the working example. https://gist.github.com/gowgopal83/e1f8a2130c95f06660498d97f1afdec4

The gist does not show the part where you create the IAM roles/policies.

@MarkoE Apologies, Please check now.

probably not the issue, but this module.iam_assumable_roles["ert_issue_lambda_role_test"].iam_role_arn should use "cert_issue_lambda_role_test" (missing a c). If that solves it by chance, it means the module isn't robust enough to accept a null there, and you should probably file an issue to the maintainers to add nullable = false to that variable or do something to prevent accidental misconfiguration

@LorenzoFelletti Thanks for checking. Missing c is a typo while copying the code. i've checked with  lambda_role = module.iam_assumable_roles["cert_check_lambda_role_test"].iam_role_arn no luck yet.

Must be something in those modules you're calling that has cyclic dependencies in them

Thanks for checking. i just created an issue on both modules. let's see how it goes.

could you try to run terraform graph -draw-cycles? Maybe it could help gathering more informations

@LorenzoFelletti Have tried that. Which threw the same cycle error.

Try adding to module iam_assumable_roles a depends_on = [module.iam_policies]

No luck with that either @LorenzoFelletti

Got some clarity on why it's failing. But there is no fix yet. Have raised a issue with Lambda module provider- https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/issues/603
